# When was the supply and demand model first used?

Tags: supply-and-demand, history

Who created the supply and demand model in economics or when was it first used?

Comment: Do you mean the mathematical model of supply and demand? The phrase "supply and demand"? or the idea?

Answer (score 1):

The Wikipedia page about the [supply and demand model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supply_and_demand) has a [History](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supply_and_demand#History) section.

According to [Hamid S. Hosseini](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/9780470999059.ch3/summary), the power of supply and demand was understood to some extent by several early Muslim scholars, such as fourteenth-century Syrian scholar [Ibn Taymiyyah](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ibn_Taymiyyah), who wrote:

> "If desire for goods increases while its availability decreases, its
>   price rises. On the other hand, if availability of the good increases
>   and the desire for it decreases, the price comes down."

[Antoine Augustin Cournot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antoine_Augustin_Cournot) first developed a **mathematical model of supply and demand** in his 1838 Researches into the Mathematical Principles of Wealth, including diagrams. However, [John Locke (1691)](http://la.utexas.edu/users/hcleaver/368/368LockeSomeConsiderationsAlltable.pdf), Adam Smith (1776) and David Ricardo (1817) also used this model.